# Establishing certain results related to functions.

Tags: functions

I made following points, but not sure if the conclusions are true or not.
I have also given a reason for every point made. So before assuming these points as true, I want to be sure if these are actually true or not. Can you guys help  me in this.

If $f(x)$ is a function from $A\rightarrow B$ and $g(x)$ is a function from $B\rightarrow C$.

**Point $1$: If $g(f(x))$ is an identity function then $f(x)$ will be one one but not necessarily onto.**

Reason:- If $g(f(x))$ is an identity function, then $g(f(x))=x$.

**Let's try to prove that $f(x)$ is one one by contradiction:-**

Suppose $f(x)$ is many one, it means two elements in A can have same image in set B like $(x_1,f(x_1)),(x_2,f(x_2))$.

$$x_1\ne x_2 \text{ and } f(x_1)=f(x_2)$$
So $g(f(x_1))$ will be same as $g(f(x_2))$ as $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. But it cannot be the case as $g(f(x))$ is an identity function, so $g(f(x_1))=x_1$ and $g(f(x_2))=x_2$, hence $f(x_1)\ne f(x_2)$.

**Let's try to prove that $f(x)$ is not necessarily onto by contradiction:-**

It can happen that range of $f(x)$ is not covering all the elements in set B. Hence $f(x)$ will not necessarily be onto.

**Point $2$: If $g(f(x))$ is an identity function $\forall x$, then $f(x)$ will be one-one and onto.**

Reason:- $f(x)$ will be one-one with the same logic explained in Point $1$. If $g(f(x))$ is an identity function $\forall x$, it means all possible values of $x$ will be there in set A and all possible values of $f(x)$ will be there in set B.

**Point 3: Can we also say that if $g(f(x))$ is an identity function for $\forall x$, then $g$ is inverse of $f$?**

Reason:- As $f(x)$ will be bijective, hence for all elements in set B, there will be a unique image in set C and all the elements in set C will be equal to all the elements in set A. Hence $g$ should be the inverse of $f$.

Comment: For point $1$, what does "an identity function" mean? $g\circ f$ is a map from $A\to C$ ...are we to assume that $C=A$?

Comment: yeah standard definition of identity function $y=x$

Comment: What is the intention/meaning of the $\forall x$ in point 2? -- Strictly speaking, you seem to unintenionally express that $C$ is a set of (identity) functions

Comment: So...why do you have a $C$?  It seems that you want $g:B\to A$.

Comment: @lulu, can you read all the points , I have explained everything over there, but I am not sure of these conclusions, so that's why checking with you guys

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, it means for all possible values of $x$, for $f(x)$

Comment: I can't follow your points.  Point $1$ only makes sense if $C=A$ (or if you fix some bijection $C\to A$).  Points $2,3$ don't make sense at all...that quantifier is a mystery.

Comment: ok let's talk about point $1$,  $f(x)$ is not necessarily a bijection as we are not sure it is onto. Suppose set A contains {1,2,3} and B contains {5,6,7,8}, f(1)=5, f(2)=6, f(3)=7 and g(5)=1, g(6)=2, g(7) =3, g(8)=4, so in this case you can see that C is {1,2,3,4} which is not equal to A

Comment: @lulu, can you read my latest comment, I have explained for point-$1$ that it is not necessary that C=A, without that also first point can be valid.

Comment: You are necessarily implying $A$ is a subset of $C$

Comment: @Robo300, only for the first point $1$ , I am saying that A can be a subset of C